# What human-edited file did I put a bad address into, for Postfix?

Tags: smtp, ip-address, postfix-mta

For my own education related to a new job, I'm trying to setup postfix on my desktop (ubuntu 12.10) machine and then send mail to it from a VM running RedHat 6.2. Both physical computers and the VM are on a local network in the building, and I have my personal login, a 'test' login and root  privilege on my desktop and the VM. I can use ssh or telnet to connect to the VM.

Looking at the VM's log files in /var/logs/work/stmpout*.log I can see I've introduced a bad network address - "176.x.y.z" instead of "172.x.y.z":

smtpout.log:20140509 17:33:40.001 UTC INFO smtpout sid=ztZK1n000101 smtp=BADCONNECT:0 dip=176.x.y.z dport=25 type=smtp msg="Bad connect" duration=21
smtpout.log:20140509 17:33:40.001 UTC INFO smtpout sid=ztZK1n000101 smtp=CLOSE dip=176.x.y.z dport=25 type=smtp

Some light grepping on the VM finds the bad value:
root@work-rh62-x64-wba:/var/log/work#  grep -R "176.x.y.z" /etc/*
/etc/work/confdb/current/smtproutingtable.xml:176.x.y.z

but nothing  helpful in /usr, /var, /net, /proc, /var, etc. 
Nor can I find any explanation of where smtproutingtable.xml comes from. I certainly didn't write it or modify it. That I'm aware of!

Comment: Always, the answer is in the question.
I couldn't identify the human-editable file I'd messed up because I'd messed up a web page of our own, which writes the .xml in question. Once I ask at work, I was reminded and indeed, there it was. Thanks for helping me get organized!

Answer (score 1):

As always, the answer is in the question.

I couldn't identify the human-editable file I'd messed up because ...I'd messed up a **web page** of our own, which writes the .xml in question.

Once I asked around at work, sending the question as I posed it here to co-workers, I was reminded and indeed, there it was. The bad value, right in the middle of a web page where I'd typed it.

Thanks for helping me get organized, stack overflow!